# エクセルで右隣のセルの値をコメントとして挿入したいのですが。ループ出来ず悩んでいます。

Tags: vba, excel

ループしない以外は、成功しております。ただ、**For i = ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Row**が構文エラーとなってます。決まった範囲ではないので、選択しているセルから最後の行までループしたく。

また、右隣（コメントの値となるセル）が空白の場合はスルーする処理も追加できたら幸いです。宜しくお願い致します。

```
Sub 右隣のセルをコメントとして挿入()
Dim r   As Range
    
 On Error Resume Next  'エラーを無視
 
 For i = ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Row

Dim Mytext As String
Mytext = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value

ActiveCell.Select
ActiveCell.AddComment Text:=Mytext


Next i

 
End Sub
```

Comment: そもそも質問の仕方からですね。汗　訂正有難うございます！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel VBAのFor文は`For i = 1 to 10`のように記述します。
ご質問のコードでは`to`が足りないため構文エラーになります。

**サンプルコード**

```
Sub 右隣のセルをコメントとして挿入()
    Dim targetCol As Integer
    targetCol = 2   'コメントを入れる列番号

    For r = Selection.Row To Cells(Rows.Count, targetCol).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim Mytext As String
        Mytext = Cells(r, targetCol + 1).Value
        If Mytext <> "" Then
            Cells(r, targetCol).AddComment (Mytext)
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！！！　教えてくださり、感謝です！！精進します！